# Custom category listings

Tags: wp-list-pages

Maybe the question is stupid sorry - I'm a beginner when it comes to WordPress.

But...

What do I have to do to have a separate page listing for articles from a given category?

Do I need a special *theme* for this? Is the *OceanWP* *theme* allows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress automatically creates an archive for each category. If you look in wp-admin, under Posts > Categories, you can click "view" to view a category and that will show you what it looks like and what the URL is.

It is possible that a theme could override this functionality, but it's unlikely. Most themes have a template to display this type of automatically-created page - either a `category.php` specifically for categories, or an `archive.php` which covers not only categories but other archives.

Comment: That's what I meant. Thank you for your comprehensive answer @WebElaine!